# Insulated glass with capillary tube

Tags: windows, glass

I just installed insulated glass with small capillary tube. The [instructions](https://www.onedayglass.com/cap-tube) say "Never install with the tube at the bottom of the window." I made a mistake and installed it with tube down. Now I am curious what the worst thing that could happen. Do I need to get new window now?

Comment: What did the manufacturer say when you asked them? Given that it's already installed, you may be best off just leaving it until it fails as the replacement cost will be similar either way.

Comment: @KMJ, good point, I need to ask manufacturer!

Comment: Any chance of reinstalling it the right way, or is all the finishing done also?

Comment: @crip659, I guess it is possible, but rather not

Comment: How is getting a new window an option but correcting the installation not an option? That makes no sense.

Comment: Was the tube sealed?

Comment: Off hand after reading the instructions, I can't see what difference up/down a sealed tube would make.  An open tube might be different.

Comment: @isherwood, I did put silicon at the end of the tube (sealed), but I did not let it dry, so it might have moved during installation process.

Comment: @isherwood, I can try to reinstall it, but I have to use putty knife to remove the glass and a bit concerned that I might scratch the glass

Comment: Remember that tape over the glass can help you to protect glass.

Comment: If you're supposed to seal the tube after installation, I don't understand why the orientation or location of the capillary tube would make any difference.  After installation, the pressure difference between the inside of the dual panes and the environment will be very little.

Comment: The only hunch I have is that putting it at the bottom increases the risk of crush damage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite possible that what matters is the orientation of the END of the tube, not whether bottom or top of window. The manufacturer can clarify.

Most likely, after installation you must seal it anyway, and the orientation then does not matter anymore.

Some windows have the tube tightly glued or taped to the edge of the pane, and so the orientation of the pane determines the orientation of the tube. Others have a "dongle" tube which can be oriented independently.

By keeping the end down, no dust will rest on the opening and thus during equalization such dust is not pulled in causing the tube to block.

Also, it's possible that by keeping the tube on the top it is not mechanically stressed due to the weight of the pane, causing the window seal to break open at the tube's entry point. In this case, the orientation of the end or sealing the end makes no difference, and relieving the mechanical stress is key, perhaps by shimming the pane at the bottom (if at all possible).

Caveat: I determined this from reading, not training or experience, so it is best to check with the manufacturer.

[image]

https://view.com/sites/default/files/documents/capillary-tube-guidelines.pdf

Also:

> Breather tubes are intended to be sealed after pressure equalization at the installed altitude.

...

> When a sealed insulating glass unit is constructed at low altitudes and then installed at higher altitudes (such as Denver) the resulting increase in altitude causes the glass panes to bow out, having a pillow shape appearance. The glass bows out because the sealed pressure at the time of assembly is greater than the pressure incurred at the higher elevation. If the pressure change is large, the insulating glass panes can fracture and/or the sealant holding the glass panes can rupture causing premature seal failure.

Ref: https://www.cardinalcorp.com/source/pdf/tsb/ig/IG13_08-2020.pdf